# Using a Loop to delete rows from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of environmental data for each country in the world.  I want to remove any entries for country that do not represent individual countries, ie 'Africa', or 'World'.  I have made a list of those values.  I am trying to loop through the df and drop each row where the country = a value in my list. There aren't that many problem entries, I have removed them before with .loc, but I'm unsure why this function is not working.  I get an error: **KeyError: '[(bunch of numbers)] not found in axis'**

````
not_country = ['Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia (excl. China & India)','EU-27','EU-28', 'Europe','Europe (excl. EU-27)',
               'Europe (excl. EU-28)', 'International transport', 'Kuwaiti Oil Fires', 'North America',
               'North America (excl. USA)', 'World', 'South America']

def clean_countries(df, lst):
    index_names = []

    for country_name in lst:
        index_names.append(df[df['country'] == country_name].index)

        for i in df:
            df.drop(index_names, inplace = True)

clean_co2_df = clean_countries(co2_df, not_country) ```
````

Comment: You very rarely need to or even want to loop through pandas data structures. `df  = df.loc[~df['Country'].isin(not_country)]`

Comment: One of the advantages of a dataframe is that you seldom have to iterate through it to get the job done. There are more efficient methods. Post the first few lines of your dayaframe so we can show you how.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the advantages of a dataframe is that you seldom have to iterate through it to get the job done.  There are usually more efficient ways. Here is a solution to your question using a sample dataframe with world population data.

```
not_country = ['Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia (excl. China & India)','EU-27','EU-28', 'Europe','Europe (excl. EU-27)',
               'Europe (excl. EU-28)', 'International transport', 'Kuwaiti Oil Fires', 'North America',
               'North America (excl. USA)', 'World', 'South America']
pop_data = {'Country': {0: 'China', 1: 'India', 2: 'USA', 3: 'Asia'}, 'Population': {0: 1439000000, 1: 1380004385, 2: 331002651, 3: 4641054775}, 'Yearly Change %': {0: 0.39, 1: 0.99, 2: 0.59, 3: 0.86}}

df = pd.DataFrame(pop_data)
print(f'BEFORE: \n {df}')

df = df.loc[df['Country'].apply(lambda x: x not in not_country)]
print(f'AFTER: \n {df}')

#output:
BEFORE: 
   Country  Population  Yearly Change %
0   China  1439000000             0.39
1   India  1380004385             0.99
2     USA   331002651             0.59
3    Asia  4641054775             0.86
AFTER: 
   Country  Population  Yearly Change %
0   China  1439000000             0.39
1   India  1380004385             0.99
2     USA   331002651             0.59
```

Comment: Using `apply` is equivalent to iterating over the dataframe. The method suggested by Paul H in the question's comments is the right method in this scenario.

Comment: @jivan apply is much faster than iterrows since it uses C extensions in Python: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/hey-pandas-why-you-no-fast-loop-e7226ed97322.  They are not equivalent.

Comment: python still needs to evaluate your lambda every time, which is not the case when using `~df['Country'].isin(not_country)`

Comment: @Jivan. I agree that Paul H's suggestion is more efficient, but my .apply() solution is valid and far more efficient than iterating over a dataframe.  It does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: The problem with apply is that it’s attractive to beginners because of its seemingly easier syntax, while the solution proposed by Paul is 40 times faster on average, and is really better practice in general. Using apply is to be thought as a last resort for when vectorization doesn’t work. If you’re working with a lot of data you will get the point very quickly. Hence the downvote.